# How can I move a geom_line behind the scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe has 3 columns (temperature plus two estimates of the same variable using different methods e.g. length).  I want to plot one as a curve and one as a scatter, which I can do.  But the line is in front of the scatter and looks ugly.  I've tried moving the line to first thing given to ggplot but it doesn't help.

EDIT: example of my data using random numbers.  `df = data.frame(temp = c(0.1,0.5,0.6,0.9,1.6),var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), var2 = c(5,4,3,2,1))`

EDIT: more detail.  Var1 and var2 are different estimates of the same variable, estimated using different methods.  E.g. height.  And I want to visualise them against temperature, with var1 as a line, and var2 as points.  But I need the line to be behind the points which I think looks better.

Below is what I've tried, the difference being the order of scatter/line passed to ggplot2.  But the line doesn't go behind the points.

```
p = ggscatter(df,x="temp",y="var2") + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = temp, y = var1), color = "blue", size = 2.5) +
  xlab('temp') +
  ylab('length')
p
```

New attempt below:

```
p = ggline(df,x="temp",y="var1", size = 2.5) + 
  geom_point(df, aes(x = temp, y = var2), color = "blue") +
  xlab('temp') +
  ylab('length')
p
```

Comment: This is not reproducible and it's not clear to me to what line or plot you're referring to. Can you edit your question to include relevant information?

Comment: Please share the data you're working with (i.e. `df`) using `dput(df)` so we can reproduce your issues.

Comment: Maybe you would benefit from making your plot from scratch with `ggplot` as your first call, instead of using `ggscatter` or `ggline`. - Also the other contributors are right, this is hard to work with, we cannot read your mind. but from reading through you probably want this: `ggplot(df, aes(x = temp)) + geom_line(aes(y = var1)) + geom_point(aes(y = var2))`

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it to provide dummy data